# Is it possible to fill two arrays simultaneously?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have two arrays:

```
var originalImagesArray = [UIImage]()
var croppedImagesArray = [UIImage]()
```

and I fill them as:

```
for i in from..<to {
        let asset: PHAsset = self.images[i] as! PHAsset
        let imageFetchOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()

        self.imageManager.requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50), contentMode: .AspectFit, options: imageFetchOptions, resultHandler: { (image: UIImage?, info: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) in
            if (image != nil) {
                print("Little: \(image!.description)")
                self.croppedImagesArray.append(image!)
            }
        })

        self.imageManager.requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 600, height: 600), contentMode: .AspectFit, options: imageFetchOptions, resultHandler: { (image: UIImage?, info: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) in
            if (image != nil) {
                print("Big: \(image!.description)")
                self.originalImagesArray.append(image!)
            }
        })
    }
```

so, in one array I save images in 50x50, but in another one by 600x600.

The problem is, when I later show images in `didSelect`, I get 2 different images.

For example in `cropped` array in index 5 I get one image, but in `original` on index 5 I get another image.

I want that were 2 same images. How can I achieve this?

1 solution is ordering images in 2 arrays the same way
2 solution is I do all that in wrong way. What I need in that case?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the problem. The code you provided, does as you'd expect. It fills two different arrays, one with a small image and another with a larger image. Is that not what you want? Please also post the didSelect method.

Comment: yes, it fills, but the order of images in arrays are different. In didSelect method I just select images from the arrays by index @Tander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs for [PHImageManager.requestImageForAsset](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHImageManager_Class/):

> By default, this method executes asynchronously. If you call it from a background thread you may change the synchronous property of the options parameter to YES to block the calling thread until either the requested image is ready or an error occurs, at which time Photos calls your result handler.

The issue is that you're invoking the `requestImageForAsset` in the order you want them, but they are completing asynchronously, which may populate the array in different orders depending on which size completes first.

If you want them in the same order, I'd recommend changing `croppedImagesArray` and `originalImagesArray` to dictionaries keyed by something that you can share between them. For example, if the actual order of the assets doesn't matter, as long as they are the same between the two collections, you could key by the asset's `localIdentifier`, then sort the dictionaries by that identifier when you enumerate the collections. If the actual order matters, pass some other sequence key (perhaps the current timestamp) and share it between the two completion handlers.

Answer (score 1):

`requestImageForAsset` is asynchronous by default so these requests may come back in any order. One simple solution would be to set the `synchronous` flag on the `PHImageRequestOptions`. Of course each call to `requestImageForAsset` will block until it's complete so it may not be an ideal solution.

---

An alternate approach that would allow the fetches to occur synchronously would be to make arrays of `UIImage?`

```
var originalImagesArray = [UIImage?]()
var croppedImagesArray = [UIImage?]()
```

and then modify your loop

```
if self.originalImagesArray.count < to {
    self.originalImagesArray.appendContentsOf(Array(count: to - self.originalImagesArray.count, repeatedValue: nil))
}
if self.croppedImagesArray.count < to {
    self.croppedImagesArray.appendContentsOf(Array(count: to - self.croppedImagesArray.count, repeatedValue: nil))
}

for i in from..<to {
    let asset: PHAsset = self.images[i] as! PHAsset
    let imageFetchOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()

    self.imageManager.requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50), contentMode: .AspectFit, options: imageFetchOptions, resultHandler: { (image: UIImage?, info: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) in
        if (image != nil) {
            print("Little: \(image!.description)")
            self.croppedImagesArray[i] = image
        }
    })

    self.imageManager.requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 600, height: 600), contentMode: .AspectFit, options: imageFetchOptions, resultHandler: { (image: UIImage?, info: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) in
        if (image != nil) {
            print("Big: \(image!.description)")
            self.originalImagesArray[i] = image
        }
    })
}
```

At the point you're using the images you could show a loading indicator or some such if the item at a particular index contained `nil`.

Comment: may be there is another way to that what I want?

Comment: Updated my answer with one possible solution which would allow the fetches to execute asynchronously.